# SurfaceView error inflating layout

Tags: android, surfaceview

Hi I'm relatively new to Android programming but I would be grateful of some help :)

I'm trying to create a toolbar that 'floats' above the main activity view. The code implements a SurfaceView which is used to draw items onto it. I've been having some difficulty with this for the past few days and can't get the app to run as it keeps fc! Logcat outputs the following errors:

**Logcat**

```
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner/com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct} android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct.onCreate(NewProduct.java:34)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  ... 11 more
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner-1.apk]
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
02-06 13:19:23.985: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  ... 20 more
```

I'm using a relative layout as I can 'snap' the toolbar to the bottom. The .xml file looks like this:

**new_product.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel 
        android:id="@+id/Panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button android:id="@+id/cut" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Cutout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NewProduct.java**

```
package com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.NewProduct.GraphicObject.Coordinates;
import com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class NewProduct extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_product);
}

public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private drawThread _thread;
    private ArrayList<GraphicObject> _graphics = new ArrayList<GraphicObject>();

    public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        _thread = new drawThread(getHolder(), this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                GraphicObject graphic = new GraphicObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle_point));
                graphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - graphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
                graphic.getCoordinates().setY((int) event.getY() - graphic.getGraphic().getHeight() / 2);
                _graphics.add(graphic);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.glass_lamp);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, paint);

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Coordinates coords;
        for (GraphicObject graphic : _graphics) {
            bitmap = graphic.getGraphic();
            coords = graphic.getCoordinates();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
        }


    int width, height;

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    paint.setAlpha(255); //0x80
    c.translate(0, 30);
    c.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg, new Matrix(), paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    //Create shape using Path
    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(20, 20);
    mPath.lineTo(100, 200);
    mPath.lineTo(400, 600);
    mPath.lineTo(240, 155);
    mPath.lineTo(250, 175);
    mPath.lineTo(20, 20);
    mPath.close();

    //Cut out a hole
    canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.XOR);
    //Fill around cut-out with opaque white
    //canvas.drawARGB(200, 255, 0, 0);
    //Restore full canvas clip for any subsequent operations
    //canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.REPLACE);

    //int h = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg, 10, 10, paint);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 10 + h + 10, paint);
    }


     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        //TODO something
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        } 
    }
}

class drawThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Panel _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public drawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }

    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class GraphicObject {
    private Bitmap _bitmap;
    private Coordinates _coordinates;

    public GraphicObject(Bitmap bitmap) {
        _bitmap = bitmap;
        _coordinates = new Coordinates();
    }

    public Bitmap getGraphic() {
        return _bitmap;
    }

    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return _coordinates;
    }

    /**
     * Contains the coordinates of the graphic.
     */
    public class Coordinates {
        private int _x = 100;
        private int _y = 0;

        public int getX() {
            return _x + _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        public void setX(int value) {
            _x = value - _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return _y + _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        }

        public void setY(int value) {
            _y = value - _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Coordinates: (" + _x + "/" + _y + ")";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `NewProduct.Panel` class when you add `<com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel android:id="@+id/Panel" ... />` element to your `new_product.xml` file, then it is wrong.

You need to move this class to a separate file, i.e. `com/odhranlynch/interiordesigner/Panel.java`

Comment: I've moved the class "Panel" to a seperate file but still having the same errors.

Comment: Do you still receive `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel`? Is your `Panel extends SurfaceView..` is in `com/odhranlynch/interiordesigner/Panel.java` file?

Comment: Sorry, not totally the same errors! ClassNotFoundException has gone. However, I now get new errors: 
    
    '02-06 14:51:49.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4658): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: NewProduct(Context,AttributeSet)'
    02-06 14:51:49.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4658):  at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
    02-06 14:51:49.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4658):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
    02-06 14:51:49.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4658):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)'

Comment: Success! As I was getting the error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: NewProduct(Context,AttributeSet)
I forgot to make the method public. Changing that method to public fix that error and now the app works! I have a created what was required. Also make sure you're xml file references the correct surface view. e.g.  <com.odhranlynch.interiordesigner.Panel references public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
Many thanks to both a.ch. and Dimitar Dimitrov :)

Answer (score 1):

Well just move the iternal classes Panel, drawThread  and GraphicObject  in separate files. This will fix the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and therefore the others.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: When you say move to different files, do you mean different .java files?

Comment: Ok so I've moved classes Panel, drawThread and GraphicObject into separate files but it still throws up the same errors